# How did Toshio die?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-grudge

In the movie, The Grudge, near the end it is shown that-

> the father of the Japanese family have killed the mother (by chasing and stabbing her?) and have drowned the black cat. He has done this in a fit of rage upon discovering the mother's affection for the professor. He then kills himself by hanging.

Throughout the movie, the little boy (Toshio) is visible to the characters who eventually die. And when the father is killing the cat, Toshio is seen hiding and cowering in a corner.

But how did Toshio actually die? (And did he?). As I remember, it is not shown clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toshio was drowned as well. In the film his spirit and the cat's spirit kind of merged.

Comment: @Roshnal If there is concrete evidence (read: not speculative information) then that would be a good question to ask on the main site, rather than tack it on to this question. :)

Comment: @TylerShads Yes you're right. :) It just came to my head the moment I read this answer so I tacked it in here.. I'll delete that comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the [FAQ on IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0391198/faq?ref_=tt_faq_sm#.2.1.6):

> **How did the Saeki family die?**
>
> Newspaper accounts say that Kayako Saeki was murdered by her husband
>   Takeo, but it doesn't give many of the details. From various elements
>   given throughout the movie, the audience is led to the conclusion that
>   Takeo found Kayako's journal and read about her love for college
>   professor Peter Kirk (Bill Pullman). Takeo went into a deep rage,
>   killed Kayako, and then drowned their son Toshio in the bathtub. Takeo
>   then hanged himself. In a deleted scene on the Director's Cut, it is
>   explained that he had actually been killed by Kayako, having been
>   hanged by large clumps of her long black hair that had sprouted from
>   the ceiling.